# Correct calculations of floats in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I'm making a game in 3D. Everything is correct in my code, although I'm confused about one thing.

When I setting up my perspective (gluPerspective) I set it to `zNear = 0.1f` and `zFar = 100.0f`. So far so good. Now, I also wanna move things just in the x or y direction via `glTranslate...`. But, the origo starts in the absolute centrum of my screen. Like I have `zFar` and `zNear`, why isn't that properly to the x and y coordinates? Now it is like if I move my sprite `-2.0f` to left on x-axis and make `glTranslate...` to handle that, it almost out of screen. And the z-axis is not behave like that. That's make it a lot more difficult to handle calculations in all directions. It's quite hard to add an unique float value to an object and for now I just add these randomly to just make them stay inside screen.

So, I have problem calculate corrects value to each object. Have I missed something? Should I change or thinkig of something? The reason that this is important is because I need to know the absolute left and right of my screen to make these calculations.

This is my `onSurfaceChanged`:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
   gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
   gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
   GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height,
                          0.1f, 100.0f);
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use gluPerspective you are transforming your coordinates from 3D world space into 2D screen space, using a matrix which looks at (0,0,0) by default (i.e. x= 0, y = 0 is in the center of the screen). When you set your object coordinates you are doing it in world space, NOT screen space.

If you want to effectively do 2D graphics (where things are given coordinates respective to their position on the screen you want to use gluOrtho2D instead.

Comment: Well, the thing is that, I have a 3D cube and a 3D world, I can't just move these properly and according to each other. So gluOrtho2D is wrong for this, right, since it's 3D?

Comment: If you want them to be orthographically projected (i.e. they appear the same size regardless of distance) to the screen, then gluOrtho2D is the right thing to use. If you want the camera to be able to move around in 3D space and things further away to appear smaller (like you get in most 3D games) then you do want gluPerspective, but you need to understand how the perspective matrix transforms things into screen space.

Comment: Thanks for answering and helping me. :). Okey, I got the use of these two commands. But I still don't get how I should make my 3D objects into 2D screen space, so I can caluclate correct. That's what confusing me..

Comment: Are you making a sprite-based (effectively 2D) game where you want to give your (possibly 3D) sprites x,y screen coordinates, or a 3D game where you want to be able to put your camera at a point in 3D space, point it at another point in 3D space and render whatever is in view of the camera?

Comment: I'm making a sprite based game there I want to give my 3D object/sprite x and y coordinates. What the camera is doing is not important. What's also important is that I coould later do collision detection in the z-direction.

Comment: Then you want to use gluOrtho2D as described in my answer.

Comment: Okey, but is my 3D object still there? The z collision detection later is needed.

Comment: All gluOrtho2D does is transform the 3D world coordinates to 2D screen coordinates, the object still exists in 3D space, with an x,y & z coordinate as specfied.

Comment: Okey, really thank you. One thing left though, all I need is to make this change to my onSurfaceChanged? So it isn't needed to iterate this every frame?

Comment: For a 2D sprite based game you should be able to set up the projection matrix using gluOrtho2D ONCE at the beginning of the game, it doesn't need to change every frame, or when the objects change/move.

Comment: Okey, I found gl.glOrthof also. Is that the same?

Comment: gluOrtho2D is the same as calling glOrthof with near = -1 and far = 1

Comment: Okey really thank you for this info. Now when I tested my objects were thousands times smaller. Should I give them coordinates according to the screen space? For example my vertices has 1.0f etc... Shall I give them 150.0f to match 150 units on the screen? Or am I thinking wrong here...

Comment: Use a modelview matrix to transform them scale them up by 150 times.

Comment: Okey, thank you so much. Will maybe create a separete question about another thing in this context.